# How can I edit this jquery code to open a menu automatically on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, pageload

I'm using a nav.js that I found on the web and would like to add some javascript to it to enable a menu to be automatically opened when the page loads. I'm not too good with js, I tried adding the class "open" to one of my catagories but it didn't seem to do anything. I suspect I need to copy the existing code, add something about it being exectuted on page load and then adding "open" would work.

This is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
        if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
          // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
          $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
          $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

          // open our new menu and add the open class
          $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
          $(this).addClass("open");
        } else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
          $(this).removeClass("open");
          $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
     });
 });
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you have a live example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav").find("li").has("ul").first().find('> a').click();
//          ^ -- more efficient to select by ID then filter
//                    ^ -- filter for submenu items only
//                               ^ -- only need the first one
//                                         ^ -- find the link
//                                                  ^ -- trigger the click
```

You can trigger the click handler programmatically.
Add this after your existing code (but within the ready handler)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger `click` event on that menu item.

Put this inside document.ready

`$("#nav > li > a#yourID").trigger('click');`

Answer (score 0):

You can call this inside document ready

```
$("#nav > li > a").addClass("open").next("ul").slideDown(350);
```